# Need to build a non copyrighted Variants.pas file:- whats in it

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have Delphi 4 and need to run MySQL database that need the support of Variants.pas

I just need to know what is in the file so i can make a variants.pas File up
method name and how the method is set up to keep standards the same
and then I will place it on torry pages for others.
If obvious its heavily copy written by our manufacturer

I've up dated everything else freeandnil...............

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you rephrase that please?

Comment: I can't understand anything that this person says.

Comment: Looks as if he wants to create a more or less "blind" implementation of Variants.pas, for some reason, and wants to know what is in it. <g>

Comment: Buy a copy of a 21st century delphi. Pointless trying to work with Delphi 4.

Comment: @David: I rather see someone use a legit copy of D4 than a pirated copy of a "21st century delphi". With Delphi 4, you could and still can do a lot, although the later versions can do a lot more, of course.

Comment: how do you know that the d4 copy is legit

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to implement your own, (open source?) Variants.pas because Delphi 4 doesn't have any. Note that in Delphi 4, Variants are still a part of System.pas and you don't need anything like Variants.pas. Just use Variants as they come with Delphi.

### Update

Just remove Variants from your uses clause and try if that works. If there are a few Variants functions missing in D4, ask a new question about that.

Comment: So maybe this confused guy thinks he needs Variants when what he just needs to do is remove the unit name from a Uses clause, and maybe make a few ifdefs, so he can get something to work in Delphi4 that was written for Delphi 5+

Comment: I don't know when Variants.pas was separated out, so it may be D6+ or so, but yes, that is probably what he should do.

Comment: Rudy Velthuis understands me as varants.pas is not part of D4

Comment: Well, as I said, you probably don't need it. Most of what is in Variants.pas in alter versions is in the System unit in Delphi 4. Just remove the Variants unit from the uses of the code you have.

Comment: Er... in "older versions", I meant.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL databases don't need any help from delphi source code.

Variants.pas is a unit that ships with Delphi 6 and later, so if you have a newer version of Delphi, you already have the full source code to it. **Update:** Try taking the reference to Variants out of your uses clause, and see if that helps the Delphi 4 code compile.

But you can not redistribute that source code.  Nor would making a copy of it do any good to anybody else.  I am not rightly able to understand you at all.

My suggestion is that you write clearly exactly what you need to do (not "build a non-copyrighted Variants.pas") and perhaps people can try to help you.

If you really want an open source Pascal variant handling class, you could look in the Lazarus LCL or the standard FreePascal libraries for one.

Comment: But it doesn't ship with Delphi 4. I assume he has some source code that has Variants in its uses and he wants to build his own implementation. He apparently doesn't know that Delphi 4 has Variants, but they are defined in System.pas.

Comment: So then he probably just needs to remove variants from his uses clause.

Comment: Yes, indeed, that is probably the only thing he must do. Could be that Variants.pas has a few extra functions D4 did not have, I don't know. He should first try to remove Variants from the uses clause.

Comment: Rudy Velthuis has the Idea I just need to make open source code But I do not know what to make.

Comment: ***You don't need it!*** Variants are part of System.pas in Delphi 4. Just remove "Variants" from your "uses" clause! In other words, what is contained in Variants.pas in Delphi 6 and later, mainly the Variant type, is contained in System.pas in Delphi 4. System.pas is always linked in, in any unit, so you can simply **remove** Variants from your **uses** clause and recompile.

Comment: Or use Uwe's brilliant "implementation". Seriously does lexdean have trouble understanding that simple fact that YOU DON'T NEED THIS UNIT.

Comment: The FPC ones probably go beyond D4 language and library level.

Answer (score 2):

According to Rudy's and others answer and comments, here is a version for the simple minded:

```
unit Variants;

interface

implementation

end.
```

At least it should work as a start.

Comment: Do you really mean "simple minded"? That's a euphemism for "stupid"; it doesn't mean "those who want to keep things simple."

Comment: I didn't mean it as "stupid" - only as "not able to understand the advice given by others".